# Verify if a folder is writable by a specific user in PHP

Tags: php, chmod

I make an intranet with a listing of few folders in order to permit of the users to download the files.

But I defined security access to the folders. Each user have the possibility to access in a specific folder.

In my intranet, I would like to verify if the folders are writable by the specific user (user of the windows session). I have used the function is_writable() but this function verify the global chmod not the user's.

Do you know a function which allows it in PHP ?

Thanks you !

Comment: What OS are you working with, linux or windows?

Answer (score 0):

By *global user* you mean the user the webserver / fastcgi wrapper runs on.

As all users access the same script but different folders, this should not be implemented on filesystem level.

The only suitable solution would be to specify the permission in a database table and check against on access.

Entity User

Entity Folder

Relation Entity User_Has_Permission_On_Folder

```
User     Has_Permission      Folder
X        read                A
Y        read+write          A
Z        read+write          B
X        read                B
...
```

I don't know your capabilities and code, but PHP, especially on Windows, has good functions to access the Domain / LDAP / Active Directory, some browsers also allow single sign on with to it using NTLM (http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris). This can be activated by Domain controller Group Policies. (Ive been using it in intranet too in my former company).

If you really want to use filesystem functions for permission, you have to create a personal script for every single user, `chown` it respectively and let it run with fast-cgi taking the script owners user as the active one. This is more complicated and less comfortable to administrate.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Yes, the goal is to run the script Taking account of the onscreen user windows. When you go to the server folder via the address \\17x.xx.xx.xx, you can open the files on which it is permitted. So I wanted to do this check before listing in php files.

I think I'll try your first solution. Thank you !